# Report Builder Filter question to search key word or add select all

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

Report Builder - Filter question

I need help as I am new to report builder.

1. I need to filter on project name and want to apply functionality that it could allow to filter on “contain” word specified in search. For example , if the project name is “North Central Towers” , and when user searches on ” Central”  or “Towers” . the filter is applied.
2. How we can apply “Select All” as in case no project name is selected, it shows null. How to address this issue?

Thanks
Liz

I tired multiple scenarios but its not working

Need to filter with any search word or need to have functionality which allows to "Select All"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is coming from a SQL Query then you can easily do this.

In this example, I'm listed Country/Region names but the theory is the same no matter what the data is.

I'm getting the data from a table called `Dim.Country` and using a dataset query that looks like this.

```
SELECT CountryDesc 
FROM Dim.Country 
WHERE (CountryDesc LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%' OR LEN(@p1)=0)
ORDER BY CountryDesc
```

Once the dataset is added, the parameter `p1` is automatically generated.

Edit the parameter properties and check the `Allow blank value("")`.

Now add a table to the report and drag the column from the dataset to it as required (in this case it was only a single column).

Now run the report. If you leave the parameter blank and hit "View Report" you will see all rows.

Now type something in the parameter and hit "View Report" again. You will now see only those rows that contain the search term.

Here's some screen shots of it in action.

[image]

[image]